# Why are the ends of my error bars not displayed?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a range of values and error bars with ggplot2 with ends but they are not displaying.

I tried varying the scales and error bar width but that did not work

Here is my code

```
plot5 <- ggplot(alpha_cDNA, aes(x = cDNA, y = ymid, colour = mark)) + geom_point() + 
         geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax), width = 0.2) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12)) + 
         theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size =12)) + scale_color_manual(values = c("chartreuse4", "aquamarine4", "steelblue4", "orchid4", "burlywood4", "gold4", "darkolivegreen4"))
```

The issue is that the error bar ends (which should be width 0.2) just don't display. I've never had this problem before

[image]

Comment: welcome to SO. Most people would like to help you, but it is very, very difficult without a reproducible example. @RobinGertenbach's answer might help, but maybe not - when boiling down your code to something representative, and reproducible, one often comes to the solution, because the problem often lies in the data itself

Comment: You should - after tyring @RobinGertenbach's answer - also change your `aes` in the `geom_errorbar` command, because it looks like your first error bar doesn't display the second half under your data point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`width = 0.2` makes the whiskers 0.2 x-units wide, your x range is in the thousands, you want to increase your width by a few orders of magnitude.

Comment: Thank you so much! changing it to 50 made it work :)